# Azure Webapp Rremove file(s) through Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

we are deploying Azure WebApps via Octopus.
We could set octopus to remove all files (except App_Data) before a publish, but we only want to remove certain files.
We can trigger powershell scripts via Octopus so maybe we can use powershell to remove file/folders in the webapp.

Are there Powershell Cmdlets to remove certain files or folders on an Azure webapp?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with PowerShell. The example below checks the file exists and then removes them.

```
If (Test-Path $FileName){
    Remove-Item $FileName
}
```

And you can use Octopus Variables within your PowerShell script if you need to. For example, a variable in your project named `$FileName` would satisfy the sample above.

You can also get the path Octopus has placed the application in:

```
$Path = $OctopusParameters['Octopus.Action[Step Name].Output.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath']
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your file properties which will you exclude in your solution. Change for  each file properties to Not content/no action/ dont  copy to output.. like this.

Or you should open your project properties and exclude your files from post build step.

Comment: It are not solution/project files that need to be removed, but files created by the application. So excluding them in the solution won't work.